# Customize admin menu item "Content"

Tags: users, routes

Is there a way to change this link to only a #. In the backend it's not possible to change this..

I want this only to be a activator for a dropdown and not a link to the content page because this page is not going to be used.

Comment: Or if anyone knows in which file this un-editable path is set?

Comment: so you want that menu without any link right?

Comment: Yes indeed. I want it only to show the dropdown and not go to /admin/content

Comment: I tried doing this now but it does not work. And this would be a removal and I just want to replace it
function mysite_admin_menu_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/content']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your user does not have access to 'Access the content overview page' or any super admin permissions.

Comment: That is not possible because the "Content" item with the icon in front of it must stay there. Because it serves as a dropdown for different content type pages

Comment: Have you even tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried it and the content block totally dissapeared from the menu